# How can I specify an endpoint class with NServiceBus.Host.exe?

Tags: nservicebus

I have have a solution that I created with the new modeler tools. This gave me
two full "endpoints" in a single solution.

Now when I run them through my automated build, I have two dlls in the same
folder that implement IConfigureThisEndpoint.

If I just run NServiceBus.Host.exe \install (to get a Windows Service), it gives
me the (expected) error that there is more than one class that can be used.

I did some searching and Udi states here:
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/3937 that "You can
specify which class you want loaded and avoid these issues - as the server
project in the pub/sub sample shows".

I looked at the pub/sub sample and I can't see how I can specify my class (at
least not at the command line).

Is there a way to get around having to modify my build to put the files in
separate folders? (Not really an easy task for me.)

Answer (score 3):

Add a config entry to your app settings with the key `EndpointConfigurationType` and the value being the assembly qualified name of the type.